# constructor problem in java

Tags: java, class

```
public class StateQueryFilter extends FieldQueryFilter {
   // private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(RecommendedParser.class.getName());

    public StateQueryFilter() {
        super("state", 5f);
        super("city", 5f);
        super("notdirectory", 5f);
        //LOG.info("Added a state query");
    }

}
```

And it reports:

```
Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Just what is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Boost the Fields:"state","city","notdirectory"

Comment: I think you'll have to just use more than one filter, if that's possible. Even if this code compiled, it would still only boost "notdirectory" and not "state" or "city".

Answer (score 6):

You can only call `super` once in a constructor, and it must be the first line.

It does not even make sense to call it more than once as you are doing. Calling `super` does not create a new object; it just lets the superclass initialize its fields. Are you really trying to initialize the same fields more than once? You probably are trying to create three separate objects, but that is not the way to do it.

See also [Using the keyword `super`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) in the Java tutorials.

Comment: There is no way it ever worked, unless they changed the rules drastically several versions ago.

Comment: *That* code has never worked - it's never been legal to call super(...) more than once.

Comment: Lol, I love how people up-vote Skeet even if the same answer was given already, yet don't up-vote that answer.  You've become a self fulfilling prophecy Jon :)

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  You are trying to construct the object 3 times, the logic is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

From [section 8.8.7 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7):

> The first statement of a constructor
>   body may be an explicit invocation of
>   another constructor of the same class
>   or of the direct superclass
>   (§8.8.7.1).

Note "first" statement - you can't have more than one.

Comment: Aww! I was going to go find it in the JLS, but now I'd look like an answer thief. :(

Answer (score 2):

I find constructors which call setter ugly.

Another option is to have a constructor which takes the arguments.

```
public StateQueryFilter() {
    super(/*state*/ 5, /* city */ 5, /*notdirectory*/ 5);
    //LOG.info("Added a state query");
}
```

However it looks like you should be doing something like

```
public class StateQueryFilter extends FieldQueryFilter {
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final boolean noDirectory;

    public StateQueryFilter(String city, String state, boolean noDirectory) {
        this.state = state;
        this.city = city;
        this.notDirectory = notDirectory;
    }
}
// later
FieldQueryFilter filter = new StateQueryFiler("Los Angeles", "California", true);
```

BTW: Don't use float values, they are almost never the best option.

Comment: Second the recommendation to avoid floats.

Also, calling setters from a constructor can actually lead to problems if the setter gets overridden in a child class do to how the vtable isn't fully constructed. Hopefully, your compiler will inline them for you, but inlining it as you do here is probably the right decision.

Comment: Some of this is dictated by the API: http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/apidocs-0.9/org/apache/nutch/searcher/FieldQueryFilter.html .